# Поменять минимальный и максимальный элемент очереди с++

Tags: c++, очередь

Задача состоит в том, чтобы поменять максимальный и минимальный элемент однонаправленной очереди на языке с++. Минимальное значение меняется на максимум, а максимум на минимум не меняется. Что не так сделал?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Spis {
    int data;
    Spis* nextNode;
};

void viewSpis(Spis* head) {
    Spis* temp = head;
    int counter = 0;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << counter + 1 << "-ый элемент : " << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->nextNode;
        counter++;
    }
}

Spis* pushBack(Spis* head, int data) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new Spis;
        head->data = data;
        head->nextNode = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    Spis* tempPtr = head;

    while (tempPtr->nextNode != NULL) {
        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNode;
    }
    Spis* newElement = new Spis;
    newElement->data = data;
    newElement->nextNode = NULL;
    tempPtr->nextNode = newElement;


    return head;
}

void change(Spis* head) {
    Spis* tempPtr = head;
    int headValue = head->data;
    int minValue = tempPtr->data;
    int maxValue = tempPtr->data;
    //Прошлись по всему листу и нашли минмальное значение
    while (tempPtr) {
        if (tempPtr->data < minValue) {
            minValue = tempPtr->data;
        }
        if (tempPtr->data > maxValue) {
            maxValue = tempPtr->data;
        }
        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNode;
    }
    cout << "Минимум: " << minValue << endl;
    cout << "Максимум: " << maxValue << endl;


    tempPtr = head->nextNode;

    while (tempPtr) {
        if (tempPtr->data == maxValue) {
            tempPtr->data = minValue;

        }if (tempPtr->data == minValue) {
            tempPtr->data = maxValue;
        }

        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNode;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0,"");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size = 5;
    Spis* head =nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        head = pushBack(head, rand() % 100 - 50);
    }
    viewSpis(head);
    change(head);
    cout <<"==================" << endl;
    viewSpis(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а вы сделали что-то не так? Что не так? Почему это не так и как так?

Comment: @Andrej дело в том, что при выводе очереди минимум меняет на максимум, а максимум выводит то же значение, что и было. Компилятор возмущён выражением '  tempPtr = head->nextNode;' после вывода максимума

Comment: что означает: "Компилятор возмущён ... после вывода максимум" - ничего не понятно, у вас программа компилируются или нет? Ошибка компилятора или времени выполнения?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch программа компилируется

Comment: так все же может поясните что же возмущает "компилятор"?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch если точнее, то разыменование пустого указателя

Comment: вы забыли, что для того чтобы поменять значение переменной в функции нужно либо передать в функцию ссылку или указатель на нее. И указатель - это тоже переменная, так что если вы его хотите изменить в функции, то должны передать указатель на указатель, либо ссылку на указатель

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Весёлая ошибка)

Смотрите, что происходит:

```
void change(Spis* head)
{
    ...

    while (tempPtr)
    {
        // Вот тут вы меняете значение максимального элемента на минимальное
        if (tempPtr->data == maxValue)
        {
            tempPtr->data = minValue;
        }
        // А вот тут вы меняете значение минимального элемента на максимальное
        if (tempPtr->data == minValue)
        {
            tempPtr->data = maxValue;
        }

        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNode;
    }
}
```

Итого имеем следующее поведение: вы корректно находите максимальный элемент и присваиваете ему минимальное значение, но дальше отрабатывает второй иф и вы присваиваете максимальное значение обратно.
Работает только для максимального элемента из-за очередности выполнения условий)

Правильно сделать так:

```
while (tempPtr)
{
    if (tempPtr->data == maxValue)
    {
        tempPtr->data = minValue;
    }
    else
    if (tempPtr->data == minValue)
    {
        tempPtr->data = maxValue;
    }

    tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNode;
}
```

Упдате: еще я подозреваю ошибку тут:

```
cout << "Максимум: " << maxValue << endl;
// Вы начинаете обход списка не с головы, а с первого элемента, тогда как сама голова может быть нуловой, на это и ругается компилятор и это даст ошибку, т.к. вы пропускаете голову своей очереди
tempPtr = head->nextNode; 

while (tempPtr) {
```

Наверное надо так:

```
cout << "Максимум: " << maxValue << endl;

tempPtr = head;

while (tempPtr) {
```

Comment: благодарю, работает!

Comment: теперь он в половине тестов меняет максимум на минимум, а минимум не меняет

Comment: @AndreyOleshkevich, гляньте Упдате)

Comment: вот теперь всё правильно, спасибо!!!

Comment: @AndreyOleshkevich, пожалуйста) Помечайте ответ как правильный, если он решает вашу проблему.